# Problem to demonstrate that it is compact

Tags: compactness

> Let $X$ be a Normed Vector Space. For any $x\in X$ and $r>0$, let $W:=\{y∈X:∥y−x∥≤r\}$. Prove: $W$ is closed and if $\dim(X)<\infty$ $W$ is compact.

I have no problems show that it is closed, but do not know how to show it is compact. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Recall that, for finite dimensional spaces, compact sets are the bounded and closed ones. Therefore, after proving that $ W $ is closed, it is enough to check that it is bounded.

Comment: That only it true for subsets of Euclidean space.